# Macbook Pro 2016 stuck on "restarting" after installing mojave

Tags: macbook-pro, software-update, performance, mojave

Whenever I try to upgrade my macbook with updates which require a system restart, it will begin the update then freeze on the screen with an apple logo and partially filled progress bar with the text "restarting".

System Info:

- MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2016, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports)
- 2.9 GHz Intel Core i5
- 8 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3

---

1. This began when I was running macOS 10.13.4 and attempted to upgrade to mojave (without installing 10.13.6 first). The same issue as described above happened so I powered the system off and restarted it.
2. The update was not installed but it booted up fine and worked normally so I tried again, this time leaving it on overnight but the same thing happened.
3. This time I tried to install the 10.13.6 update before mojave but got the same results when installing 10.13.6. Upon reboot the system was still at 10.13.4
4. I tried installing the 10.13.6 combo update, same thing happened
5. I tried resetting my PRAM with Command + Option + P + R but that didnt change anything
6. I booted into recovery mode and ran first aid on my disk
7. I booted into recovery mode and reinstalled the macOS. This succeeded and set me at 10.13.6, hooray.
8. I opened the app store and tried to install the security update before moving on to mojave, just in case. System rebooted, began install, then froze on the "restarting" step.

I am under the impression there is an error during the install which also prevents the reboot sequence but I don't know how to track it down. Does anyone have insight into what is happening here?

Comment: start in safe mode and use `fsck` to inspect your disk

Comment: I gave that a shot but it came up "the volume appears to be OK".

Comment: sorry, I forgot to say, you have to run `fsck` at least 5 times, Apple recommends 10 times. Also do you have USB disk with OSX to start from, or do you have a Time machine back up ?

Comment: Interesting, I can give that a try on my next update. It looks like I found a workaround for now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up trying to install the updates from safe mode and that worked. It doesn't solve the issue but is an acceptable workaround for me.